# PHP Replace Custom Tags With List Tags

Tags: php

I have a database table that will store a description of a product. I want the user to be able to insert custom “[FEATURES]” tags to be able to list all of the features of the product quickly or without having to use a WYSIWYG editor or having to write their own html. So as shown below, the user will be able to specify the opening features tag and closing features tag list like so :

```
[FEATURES]
Feature # 1 would go here!
Feature # 2 would go here!
Feature # 3 would go here!
Feature # 4 would go here!
Feature # 5 would go here!
[/FEATURES]
```

So as shown above this is how the user would specify the list of features, but I would want them output in an un-ordered list like below:

```
<ul>
<li>Feature # 1 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 2 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 3 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 4 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 5 would go here!</li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping I could use the simple str_replace function

```
str_replace("\n", "<li>", $string)
```

but I’m having trouble trying to figure how how to properly do so.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDITED:
I forgot to include that on the outside of those [FEATURES] tags, there will be random description surrounding it, and I only want the output of the features list instead of accepting any other description on the output. So I'm thinking preg_match_all function may be necessary, just not quite sure how to put them together.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of solving it:

- Separately replace both opening and closing `[FEATURES]` with respective `<ul>`
- handle all three possible new lines: `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`

Aaron, here is a basic solution:

```
<?php

$input = <<<INPUT
[FEATURES]
Feature # 1 would go here!
Feature # 2 would go here!
Feature # 3 would go here!
Feature # 4 would go here!
Feature # 5 would go here!
[/FEATURES]
INPUT;

// Add basic tags
$input = str_replace("[FEATURES]", "<ul>", $input);
$input = str_replace("\r\n", "</li>\n<li>", $input);
$input = str_replace("[/FEATURES]", "</ul>", $input);

// Clear up tags we don't need
$input = str_replace("<ul></li>", "<ul>", $input);
$input = str_replace("<li></ul>", '</ul>', $input);

echo $input;
```

Output:

```
<ul>
<li>Feature # 1 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 2 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 3 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 4 would go here!</li>
<li>Feature # 5 would go here!</li>
</ul>
```

Check how it works here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cd7fe761f59802c81c8832108c32c9434a4e9f0

Answer (score 1):

1. Explode the string into lines
2. Surround each line by `<li>` tags
3. Glue everything together and surround items with `<ul>` tag

Code :

```
echo "<ul>" . implode('', 
    array_map(function ($item){ return '<li>' . $item . '</li>';},
        explode("\n", $string)
    )
)
. '</ul>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fts = <<<EOD
[FEATURES]
Feature # 1 would go here!
Feature # 2 would go here!
Feature # 3 would go here!
Feature # 4 would go here!
Feature # 5 would go here!
[/FEATURES]
EOD;

$ul = "<ul>";
foreach(explode("\r\n", $fts) as $str){
    $ul .= !strpos($str, "FEATURES") ? "<li>".$str."</li>" : "";
}
$ul .= "</ul>";

echo $ul;
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Feature # 1 would go here!</li>
    <li>Feature # 2 would go here!</li>
    <li>Feature # 3 would go here!</li>
    <li>Feature # 4 would go here!</li>
    <li>Feature # 5 would go here!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wait, I just noticed that there's still a problem though. Say that there is other text description around the outsides of the [FEATURES] tags like shown below:

Comment: blaaahhh blahhh blahhh  [FEATURES] list of features would go here [/FEATURES] blahh blahh blahh (some random description on the outsides of the FEATURES tags. Wouldn't we have to do preg_match_all or replace?

Comment: @AaronEsteban as long as each feature is on its own line it will still work. `strpos()` checks if the word "FEATURES" appears *anywhere* on the line

Comment: No, because I've tested it. If you check below as the input with description on the outside of those feature tags, that description is NOT supposed to be inside the final output. I'll leave you an example below of what I'm referring to....

Comment: $fts = <<<EOD
SOME RANDOM DESCRIPTION HERE ABOVE IT - BLAHHH BLAHH BLAHH...
[FEATURES]
Feature # 1 would go here!
Feature # 2 would go here!
Feature # 3 would go here!
Feature # 4 would go here!
Feature # 5 would go here!
[/FEATURES]
SOME RANDOM DESCRIPTION HERE BELOW IT- BLAHHH BLAHH BLAHH...
EOD;

Comment: @AaronEsteban I'm not sure how you're formatting things, but I just tested it too and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
<?php
$Input = "";
$Input .= "[FEATURES]\n";
$Input .= "Fits in pocket\n";
$Input .= "Waterproof\n";
$Input .= "2-year warranty\n";
$Input .= "[/FEATURES]";

$NewInput = preg_replace_callback("~\[FEATURES\]((?:(?!\[/FEATURES\]).)*)\[/FEATURES\]~is",
        function ($Match) {
            return preg_replace("~(?<=[\r\n]|^)([^\r\n]*)(?=[\r\n]|$)~is", "<li>$1</li>", preg_replace("~^\s|\s$~is","",$Match[1]));
        }, $Input??"");

$NewInput = "<ul>\n".$NewInput."\n</ul>";

echo $NewInput;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d0d622983acfa9f1ad2156939cc435eecc0dd4d